# Swift Clear webview cache on app termination

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, swift3

I want to clear a **UIWebView**'s **URLCache, Javascript(local storage)** when the app terminates.

I have implemented the following code on a button press. The functionality works as intended on button press.

```
func clearEverything() {
    print("cleared")
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
    URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0

    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "localStorage.clear();")
    let cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! {
        cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

}
```

In **AppDelegate**'s func **applicationWillTerminate**, I have used the following code:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    print("app terminated")
    clearEverything()
}

func clearEverything() {
    print("cleared from App Delegate")
    URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    URLCache.shared.diskCapacity = 0
    URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity = 0

    ViewController().webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "localStorage.clear();")
    let cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! {
        cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

}
```

Whenever I terminate the app, I get the following error:

[image]

[image]

Suggest me the best way to achieve this functionality without crashing the application.

Thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you try clearing it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: Getting the exact same error there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working, but only when the app is terminated with VC with **UIWebView** being displayed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationWillTerminate), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)
}

func applicationWillTerminate() {
    clearBtnPressed(Any.self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seem like ViewController don't have an instance of webview

> ViewController().webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from:
>   "localStorage.clear();")

clear everything in viewWillDisappear of webview

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // codes
}
```

the problem is webview instance is not there when you're about to close the app, then how about you instantiate a webview inside of App Delegate when you start an app, and use that instance to show in a specific view. this way webview instance should be available every time for you to call clearEverything before closing an app.

Comment: Still JavaScript cache is present, not being cleared